# how can i send data from RecyclerView adapter to viewmodel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-adapter, android-viewmodel

i have a problem the postion value is lost when sending it to viewmodel

```
class itemAdapter_Fruit (private val context:fruit , val dataset:List<FruitsType>):RecyclerView.Adapter<itemAdapter_Fruit.ViewHolder>() {
class ViewHolder (view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val fruitImage:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_image)
    val fruittext:TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.Fruit_name_text)
    init {
        view.setOnClickListener{
            val position =adapterPosition
            datamodel().setpos(position)
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fruit2_to_clicked_Item)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder (parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): itemAdapter_Fruit.ViewHolder {
 val adapterlayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fruits_list,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(adapterlayout)
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: itemAdapter_Fruit.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = dataset[position]
    holder.fruitImage.setImageResource(item.ImageFruitId)
    holder.fruittext.text=context.getText(item.FruitNameId)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataset.size
}
```

}

when i trying to send the data to viewmodel from recycler adapter it's lost

Comment: Can I see your observer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask:
You've left out some key information. Like ... What does "it's lost" mean? What is `dataModel()`? How is `setPos(int)` defined?

Comment: The data model is my view model class

Comment: Position lost mean that when I send Position value to view model it still null